# How to check woocommerce single product tag

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to check product tag at single product page.

For example, when user access single product page

if that product tag is "adult"

redirect to main page.

I found `is_product_tag()` but this function only work at archive page.

Is there a way to know the tags on a single product page?

Answer (score 2):

To check if the product has the tag, you can use [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) or [`is_object_in_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_object_in_term).

```
has_term( 'tag_slug_or_ID', 'product_tag' )
```

Or:

```
// checking if the product has any tag
is_object_in_term( $product_id, 'product_tag' )
```

```
// checking if the product has a given tag
is_object_in_term( $product_id, 'product_tag', 'tag_slug_or_ID' )
```